# Scaling entire imgui (glfw) interface

Tags: python, imgui

I'm using imgui with the GLFW renderer, in Python.

Is there a platform-independent way to apply a scale factor to the entire imgui interface?

On high DPI (Windows) and Retina (macOS) displays, my GUI elements are too tiny, and I'd like to provide a way to scale the elements accordingly.

Assume that I already know how to get the system scale factor (it's easy enough with `glfw.get_window_content_scale(...)`), and am just looking for a way to scale the GUI given a specific scale factor.